# JSON parse error: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13))

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, parsing

Need help with parsing from json, i have a REST method that return pagination with sorting and filtering, but my job in name, that ends with \ like david\ not to throw any exceptions instead remove it \ in code. Below my UserController class:

> ```
> @PutMapping
> public PageDTO<UserDTO> find(@RequestBody PageRequest<UserFilter, UserSort> request) {
>     return userService.find(request);
> }
> ```

Below PageRequest and UserFilter

> ```
> @Data
> @Builder
> @AllArgsConstructor
> @NoArgsConstructor
> public class PageRequestDTO<UserFilter, UserSort> {
>
>     private Integer size;
>     private Integer page;
>     private UserFilter filter;
>     private UserSort sort;
>
> }
>
> @Data
> @Builder
> @NoArgsConstructor
> @AllArgsConstructor
> public class UserFilterDTO {
>     
>     private String name;
> }
> ```

And my exception

> ```
> 2022-sep.-09 15:55:44.786 WARN  [http-nio-8083-exec-3] c.e.s.c.a.CommonControllerAdvice - Handling undefined exception: JSON parse error: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
>  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 35] (through reference chain: com.example.spring.dto.PageRequest["filter"]->com.example.spring.dto.UserFilter["nameSearchText"])
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
>  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 35] (through reference chain: com.example.spring.dto.PageRequest["filter"]->com.example.spring.dto.UserFilter["nameSearchText"])
>   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:389)
>   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:185)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
>  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 35] (through reference chain: com.example.spring.dto.PageReques["filter"]->com.example.spring.dto.UserFilter["nameSearchText"])
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:393)
> org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:378)
>   ... 51 common frames omitted
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
>  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 35]
> ```

i tryied this property "spring:jackson:parser:allow-unquoted-control-chars: true" in my yml file, but instead of above exception i got this one

```
"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 50] (through reference chain: com.example.service.spring.dto.PageRequest[\"filter\"])"
```

**JSON sample**

```
{ "pageSize":5, "pageIndex":0, "filter": { "name": "user_2\" } }
```

Comment: How is your JSON looking alike?

Comment: if u speack about request -> {
    "pageSize":5, 
    "pageIndex":0,
    "filter": {
    "name": "user_2\"
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lajos' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73664111/139985) explains, the problem is that `\"` is inadvertently escaping the double quote.  That causes it to not be treated as a string end.  The rest of the JSON is then parsed as part of the quoted string until the parser gets to the end.

Now I surmise that the input text actually ends with a `CR` `LF` sequence.  When the parser encounters the `CR` it says

```
Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13))
```

because the ASCII code for `CR` is 13 decimal.

The error message seems to imply that the CR *would* be legal if it was *quoted*.  In fact, no characters less than decimal 32 are permitted in JSON strings at all ... unless you express them as a JSON *escape sequence*.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but my job is handle this broken json, can i do some parser, that can read my example and chack if it "\" in the end of name and add one more "\" if true?

Comment: "my job is handle this broken json".  You unfortunate person! The bad news is that you are going to have to write a bunch of code to handle it.  Either by recognizing and fixing the "syndrome" accurately before parsing, or by writing a custom parser for this NOT JSON input.  The good news is that you are well within your rights to reject the input as invalid.

Comment: I would push back.  If your client insists on demanding this stupidity, charge them more money for writing a custom "NOT JSON" parser for them, and make it crystal clear that you CANNOT be held responsible for data corruption caused by your software "fixing" the bad data in the wrong way, or by ignoring correct escapes that shouldn't be ignored.  Basically, what you are being asked to parse is ambiguous.

Comment: And to answer your question directly ... with another question: how do you know if the `\"` is at the end of a string or in the middle of a string?  And, more importantly, how do you code your parser so that >it< can make the right decision about whether or not to treat the backslash in a special way?

Answer (score 1):

In the

```
{ "pageSize":5, "pageIndex":0, "filter": { "name": "user_2\" } }
```

sample JSON the `\"` part means that you escape the quote, which will cause troubles when the JSON is being parsed. You need to receive a String where the `\` character is escaped, as

```
{ "pageSize":5, "pageIndex":0, "filter": { "name": "user_2\\" } }
```

Now, it's quite possible that you have the JSON above somewhere, escaping the backslash, but this ends up with a single backslash on the receiving end. In that case you need to escape the escaped backslash (yeah, it sounds weird, but sometimes that's the case), as

```
{ "pageSize":5, "pageIndex":0, "filter": { "name": "user_2\\\\" } }
```

If you need further help, then you will also need to provide further information.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but my job is handle this broken json, can i do some parser, that can read my example and chack if it "\" in the end of name and add one more "\" if true?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string in your example is not a valid one:
`'{ "pageSize":5, "pageIndex":0, "filter": { "name": "user_2\" } }'`
You must return `400 bad request` because of malformed request. The client is just not a proper REST client and instead of supporting bad requests fixing the client would be the real solution.

People spent a lot of time on writing a proper JSON parser and if you add a custom one for malformed JSONs, it will be a potential security issue. For example you fix the above JSON string by replacing `\` with `\\`, then I add a string something like `"user_2\"..."` which will be changed to `"user_2\\"..."`, which is invalid again. If this is filled with user input, then the user might be able to inject another property in the `...` part of the message, which can be used to replace another property, which is not filled by the user. So it is a very bad idea to fix or write parsers without knowing what you are doing. Whoever gave you this job is completely incompetent from both programming and information security perspective.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but my job is handle this broken json, can i do some parser, that can read my example and chack if it "\" in the end of name and add one more "\" if true?

Comment: @ZeroHero You have to think it through how to find the "end" and where it can break when you try to fix it. Otherwise it can be used against your system. The upper example is just one way to inject attacker data. Even if I start with an existing parser and override the closing `"` to `\"` it won't work, because the other strings end properly. How do you know it is the string that should end with `\"`, how do you know you are at the end of string. not in the middle of it?